# how to make the enter key process work in jquery

Tags: jquery

how to make the enter key process work in jquery. when press enter it will be processed.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ziunk09/s3zs4gpf/1/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#top-search-form .search-button', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var targrt = $(this).prev('input.search-input');
    targrt.animate({
        width: ["toggle", "swing"],
        height: ["toggle", "swing"],
        opacity: "toggle"
    }, 500, "linear");

    return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="top-search-form" class="header-search-light">
    <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search...." required="" style="display: none;">
    <button class="search-button">
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: The demo is working. What's the issue?

Comment: example we want to find abcd. at press enter then he will be processed

Comment: Unable to understand what you are trying to do and what problem you are facing?????

Comment: try putting this new scrip in my demo. when we process he will run. I want to be like that.


<div class="form_search">
        <form role="search" class="searchform" id="searchform" method="get">
          <input type="search" placeholder="Search …" id="search" value="" name="" class="field">
          <input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit" class="submit">
        </form>
      </div>

Comment: when press enter exit result like {"error": "Please use POST request"} ..

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
$('.search-input').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
    ////////// Do your further action here

        var target = $(this);
        target.animate({
            width: ["toggle", "swing"],
            height: ["toggle", "swing"],
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 500, "linear");

        return false;
    }
});
```